# How to associate one file type to another in visual studio code?

Tags: docker, vim, visual-studio-code, dockerfile

I have a project with two separate docker files.

- Dockerfile
- Dockerfile.dev

VSCode can recognize the first file as a docker file, but not so much luck with the second one. There is no syntax highlighting, and the file hasn't got the docker icon.

Is there any workaround like in vim:

`autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead Dockerfile.* set filetype=dockerfile`

Can I have some kind of association between Dockerfile.dev and Dockerfile to trick VSCode that Dockerfile.dev is a Docker file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CMD** + **Shift** + **P** (CTRL + Shift + P for Linux/Windows) then type **> Change Language Mode**, press **Enter**, "Configure File Association for '.dev'..." and select Docker. Done!

Comment: This sadly last just for the current session, however, I found a way to do it. In case someone runs over the same issue just put this in the settings.json: 
"files.associations": {
  "Dockerfile.*": "dockerfile"
}